# SIGALRM handler does not run when inside another handler

Tags: c, signals, alarm

So I am working on an assignment on signals for a class and our goal is to catch the SIGINT signal and ask to quit if the user enters Ctrl-C 5 times. If the user doesn't reply to the exit prompt within ten seconds, it should automatically quit.

My implementation for this is to setup a handler for SIGINT without masking SIGALRM and then call `alarm()` from inside the SIGINT handler but from the output I'm getting, it seems like the SIGALRM handler doesn't run until the SIGINT handler is done running.

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* standard I/O functions                         */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* exit                                           */
#include <unistd.h>    /* standard unix functions, like getpid()         */
#include <signal.h>    /* signal name macros, and the signal() prototype */

/* first, define the Ctrl-C counter, initialize it with zero. */
int ctrl_c_count = 0;
int got_response = 0;
#define CTRL_C_THRESHOLD  5 

/* the Ctrl-C signal handler */
void catch_int(int sig_num)
{
  /* increase count, and check if threshold was reached */
  ctrl_c_count++;
  if (ctrl_c_count >= CTRL_C_THRESHOLD) {
    char answer[30];

    got_response = 0;
    alarm(5);

    /* prompt the user to tell us if to really
     * exit or not */
    printf("\nReally exit? [Y/n]: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(answer, sizeof(answer), stdin);
    if (answer[0] == 'n' || answer[0] == 'N') {
      printf("\nContinuing\n");
      fflush(stdout);
      /* 
       * Reset Ctrl-C counter
       */
      ctrl_c_count = 0;
      got_response = 1;
    }
    else {
      printf("\nExiting...\n");
      fflush(stdout);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}

/* the SIGALRM signal handler */
void catch_alrm(int sig_num)
{
  printf("\nGot to alarm handler\n");
  if (got_response == 0)
  {
    printf("User taking too long to respond. Exiting ...\n");
    exit(0);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  struct sigaction sa;
  sigset_t mask_set;  /* used to set a signal masking set. */

  /* setup mask_set */
  sigfillset(&mask_set);

  sigdelset(&mask_set, SIGALRM);

  /* set signal handlers */
  // set up the signal handler for Ctrl-C (SIGINT)
  sa.sa_handler = catch_int;
  sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

  // set up signal handler for alarm (SIGALRM)
  sa.sa_handler = catch_alrm;
  sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

  while(1)
  {
    pause(); 
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the SIGALRM handler doesn't run until the SIGINT handler is finished? I know I probably shouldn't be printing and stuff from inside a signal handler but as I said this is for a class and I was told to do it this way only.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: A signal handler should be short, and not do anything that can halt the process. You can't stop for input for example. And `printf` is not a signal safe function. You need to take a step back, and read a bit more about signals and signal-handling. And reconsider your design (or rather your implementation of it).

Comment: Also note that some signals *block* other signals.

Comment: I know printf isn't a signal safe function but I am not allowed to change this implementation as it is for a class. All I was allowed to do was to create a handler for SIGALRM and call alarm from inside the SIGINT handler.

Comment: Did your teacher provide the code for the `SIGINT` handler? Then you really should call out the teacher for leading by *very* bad example.

Comment: Yeah I was provided the code for the SIGINT handler and the main function. I can talk to the professor but I really don't think that's going to change much. Does SIGINT block other signals from being detected even if I have them unmasked via `sigdelset`? And the handler for SIGALRM runs just not until the SIGINT handler is done running for some reason

Comment: Add `sa.sa_flags=0;` and `sa.sa_mask=mask_set;` before the first call to sigaction. Otherwise it's unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice that I hadn't set the mask set in the struct.